# How can I replicate `algorithm` header type functions?

Tags: c++, c++20

Just like algorithms in algo header like
`std::sort(std::begin(), std::end(), greater)`
where `greater` is a `bool func`

I am trying to do the same for understanding as how it works actually.
So I am trying to do the same by
1 ->  making a lambda func in a separate namespace
2 -> making a separate function like `std::sort` in other namespace
3 -> passing a vector and it supposed to return a pointer to the  element to find

And i am getting error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:41:22: error: no matching function for call to 'chk(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, lambda::<lambda(auto:16, int)>&, int)'
   41 |     auto l {test::chk(series.begin(), series.end(), lambda::find, 50)};
      |             ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:22:10: note: candidate: 'template<class auto:17, class auto:18, class auto:19> auto test::chk(auto:17, auto:18, std::function<bool(auto:19, int)>&, int)'
   22 |     auto chk(auto start, auto end, std::function<bool (auto, int)>& find, int what)
      |          ^~~
<source>:22:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:41:22: note:   'lambda::<lambda(auto:16, int)>' is not derived from 'std::function<bool(auto:19, int)>'
   41 |     auto l {test::chk(series.begin(), series.end(), lambda::find, 50)};
      |             ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As per the error I tried putting `std::iterator` at `chk func` call at line no `41` but it gives even more error

help me with this

code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    //
#include <functional>    //std::function
#include <iterator>     //std::iterator

using vec = std::vector<int>;

namespace lambda
{
    auto find{
        [](auto start, int what) -> bool
        {
            if(*start == what)
                return true;
        }
    };
};

namespace test
{
    auto chk(auto start, auto end, std::function<bool (auto, int)>& find, int what)
    {
        if(start == end)
            return end;
            
        for(;start != end; ++start)
        {
            if(find(start, what))
                return start;
        }
        
        return end;     //is this really necessary?
    }
};

int main()
{
    vec series{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 50, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    
    auto l {test::chk(series.begin(), series.end(), lambda::find, 50)};
    
    //test
    std::cout << "Old array\n";
    
    for(int x: series)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
        
    std::cout << "\nNew array\n";
    
    *l = 666;
    
    for(int x: series)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
}
```

Comment: `find` is not supposed to be a `std::function` or reference to one. It should also just have type `auto`. See how `std::sort` is declared: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: Most of the algorithms on cppreference include a sample implementation

Comment: Your problem is that there's nothing to tell the compiler that the `auto` in the type of `find` is the same as the `auto` for `start`. It can't deduce the types

Comment: What changes can I make so that I can make the compiler believe that those auto are the same?

Comment: Don't use auto, use a single template type instead

Comment: If you want to mimic `std::find`, then the `find` argument should be just `auto` (or, more sanely, `auto&&`). Then you won't have this problem at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `auto` you end up with each parameter having a different type and the compiler has no way to deduce what all of the parameters should be (see the `template argument deduction/substitution failed` part of the error message).

Replacing the `auto` with normal templates gives:

```
template <typename A>
bool find =
        [](A start, int what) ...

template <typename B, typename C, typename D, typename E>
E chk(A start, B end, std::function<bool (C, int)>& find, int what);
```

The compiler has no way to know that `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` should all be the same type.
If you change `chk` to:

```
template< typename Iterator >
Iterator chk(Iterator start, Iterator end, std::function<bool (Iterator, int)>& find, int what)
```

We're closer but still have two issues:

1. You're taking `find` by a non-const reference so the types have to match exactly
2. The compiler still can't deduce the type required for the `find` lambda as `std::function` prevents this kind of type deduction.

If we change to the more conventional form of the std algorithms of just taking the predicate as a template:

```
template< typename Iterator, typename Predicate >
Iterator chk(Iterator start, Iterator end, Predicate find, int what)
```

Then your code compiles. This has the added benefit of not involving the overhead of `std::function` and will use (and probably inline) the lambda directly.

You can use a [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) to restrict the type of `Predicate` to match your requirements to improve compiler errors if used with an incorrect predicate.

`find` only ever returns true, you need to return in all cases otherwise your code has undefined behaviour:

```
auto find{
  [](auto start, int what) -> bool
  {
      if(*start == what)
          return true;
      else
          return false;
  }
```

Or more simply:

```
auto find{
  [](auto start, int what) -> bool
  {
      return *start == what;
  }
```

Finally your predicate is unusual for a std algorithm in that it takes an iterator rather than a value, changing it to a value results in:

```
namespace lambda
{
    auto find{
        [](int value, int what)
        {
            return value == what;
        }
    };
};

namespace test
{
    template< typename Iterator, typename Predicate >
    Iterator chk(Iterator start, Iterator end, Predicate find, int what)
    {
        for(;start != end; ++start)
        {
            if(find(*start, what))
                return start;
        }

        return end;
    }
};
```

Note I've also removed the `start == end` check as it's unnecessary.